# how to get the position of a number in matrix?

Tags: javascript, c, algorithm

How can I get the number's position by c or Javascript.
It is a ordered number array,like

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

how can I make a function to get the number 3 is 2-1,and 6 is 3-2

Thank you very much!

Comment: is this matrix a 2d array?

Comment: Are the entries unique?

Comment: Is the order absolute, i.e. if you flatten the 2d array to a linear array by concatenating all rows, is that linear array still ordered?

Comment: arrays are zero based.

Comment: Are the elements in this 2D array are unique?

Comment: What data structure is storing them?

Comment: rows : (n + 1) / 2, cols : (n + 1) % 2 + 1, array[][m] : {(n+m-1)/m}-{(n+m-1)%m + 1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this in javascript

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];

var getPos = function(elem, data) {
  var result = '';
  data.forEach(function(value, index) {
    value.forEach(function(v, i) {
      if (v == elem) result += (index + 1) + '-' + (i + 1);
    });
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getPos(5, data));
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you could write a function that would implement the following pseudo-code:

```
//...
for(i=0 ; i<ARRAY_SIZE ; i++)
    {
    if(array[i] == desired_num) 
    return i;
    else
    i++;
    } 
return -1; // return error if desired_num not found
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a continuous ordered two-dimensional array you can do something like this to get the indices. (Notice `+1` as per your example)

```
int x = floor(number/2) +1:
int y = (number+1)%2 +1;
```

If you are using arrays you should be able to jump the the right index without needing to loop like I see other answers suggesting.

```
array[x][y]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this

```js
var table = (new Array (10)).fill(new Array(10).fill("")).map( e=> e.map( f => ~~(Math.random()*1000))),
  results = [];
function findInTable(t, q){
  var finds = {x:[],y:[]};
  t.forEach( (a, i) => {j = a.indexOf(q); ~j && (finds.x.push(j+1), finds.y.push(i+1))});
  return finds;
}
results = findInTable(table, 777);

document.write("<pre>" + table[0] + "\n" + table[1] + "\n" + table[2] + "\n" + table[3] + "\n" + table[4] + "\n" + table[5] + "\n" + table[6] + "\n" + table[7] + "\n" + table[8] + "\n" + table[9] + "\n" +"</pre>");
document.write("<pre> Searched for " + 777+ " and found at:\n" + JSON.stringify(results, null, 4) + "</pre>");
```